# Tensorflow object detection API - training a model on multiple GPUs

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

My question refers to the relation between number_of_steps and batch_size when training a model using the Tensorflow object detection API.

When I increase batch size. e.g. from 1 to 2, can I then half the number_of_steps and receive the same accuracy for the model?